# Creating loop using table list and call all table one by one

Tags: sql, loops

I have a list of tables from this query

```
select table_name  from all_tab_columns  where column_name='EXCN_ID'
```

I want to fetch all required columns using this query

```
select B.* 
from t_int_excn_log A, TABLE B
where A.excn_strt_tm < sysdate-7  and A.excn_id=B.excn_id;
```

Need you help for looping the table list, such that, instead of TABLE, it will call all table one by one as per the previous query.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: `CURSOR` perhaps?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

you can use cursor for this case.

```
declare @name varchar(200)
declare cur cursor for 
select   table_name  from all_tab_columns  where column_name='EXCN_ID'
open cur
fetch next from @name
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    select B.* 
    from t_int_excn_log A, @name B
    where A.excn_strt_tm < sysdate-7  and A.excn_id=B.excn_id;
fetch next from @name
end
close cur
deallocate cur
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct query?. Because if I execute this in Toad, there seems to be lot of errors. Could you please send me the correct syntax

Comment: That is for SQL Server DB

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
DECLARE CURSOR cur IS 
       select   table_name  from all_tab_columns  where column_name='EXCN_ID'
       FROM occupancy WHERE occupied_dt = SYSDATE;
    cur_rec table_name%ROWTYPE;
 BEGIN
    OPEN cur;
    LOOP
       FETCH cur INTO cur_rec;
       EXIT WHEN Cur%NOTFOUND;
       select B.* 
        from t_int_excn_log A, cur_rec B
        where A.excn_strt_tm < sysdate-7  and A.excn_id=B.excn_id;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
 END;
```